# Where is a dimension structure tab in Visual Studio?

Tags: structure, visual-studio-2019, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimension

Where can I find a dimension structure tab in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019? Is there a shortcut for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. You just have to simply double click on one of your created dimensions in the solution explorer.